# Reusing handles from cURL multi handler

Tags: php, curl

Well, I am attempting to reuse the handles I've spawned in the initial process, however after the first run it simply stops working. If I remove (or recreate the entire handler) the handles and add them again, it works fine. What could be the culprit of this?

My code currently looks like this:

```
<?php
echo 'Handler amount: ';
$threads = (int) trim(fgets(STDIN));
if($threads < 1) {
    $threads = 1;
}

$s = microtime(true);
$url = 'http://mywebsite.com/some-script.php';

$mh = curl_multi_init();
$ch = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $threads; $i++) {
    $ch[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch[$i], array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:21.0) Gecko/20130213 Firefox/21.0',
        CURLOPT_REFERER => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY => true
    ));

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
}

while($mh) {
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while($running > 0);

    $e = microtime(true);
    $totalTime = number_format($e - $s, 2);
    if($totalTime >= 1) {
        echo floor($threads / $totalTime) . ' requests per second (total time '.$totalTime.'s)' . "\r";
        $s = microtime(true);
    }
}

foreach($ch as $handler) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $handler);
    curl_close($handler);
}

curl_multi_close($mh);
?>
```

When I have `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` set to `true`, I see many "additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0" messages, I read about them on a different question, and it seems that it is caused by some obvious things:

- Too fast
- Firewall
- ISP restricting

AFAIK, this is not it, because if I recreate the handles every time, they successfully complete at about 79 requests per second (about 529 bytes each)

My process for reusing the handles:

1. Create the multi handler, and add the specified number of handles to the multi handler
2. While the mutli handler is working, execute all the handles
3. After the while loop has stopped (it seems very unlikely that it will), close all the handles and the multi curl handler

It executes all handles once and then stops.

This is really stumping me. Any ideas?

Comment: You close them with `curl_close($handler);`, how do you expect them to work afterwards?

Comment: No, I close them after the while loop is done. `while($mh) {`

Comment: @DavidHarris How exactly are you trying to *reuse the handles*?

Comment: I'll update the OP with the process, Ranty. I've done this before with regular handles, but with parallel it doesn't seem to want to cooperate.

Comment: Uncondtionally invoking curl_multi_exec() like this will cause your code to busy-loop like crazy. It will be very bad for multi-threading.

Comment: What do you propose I do, then?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem (using C++ though) and found out that I need to remove the curl easy handle(s) and add it back in again. My solution was to remove all handles at the end of the curl_multi_perform loop and add them back in at the beginning of the outer loop in which I reuse existing keep-alive connections:

```
for(;;) // loop using keep-alive connections
{
    curl_multi_add_handle(...)
    while ( stillRunning ) // curl_multi_perform loop 
    {
        ...
        curl_multi_perform(...)
        ...
    }
    curl_multi_remove_handle(...)
}
```

Perhaps this also applies to your PHP scenario. Remember: don't `curl_easy_cleanup` or `curl_easy_init` the curl handle in between.

If you turn on [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) you can follow along in the console and very that your connections are indeed reused. That has solved this problem for me.

Comment: Can confirm the same thing happening in PHP. My script kept saving the first group of files over and over with the names of following files in the list. This answer helped fix it. Thanks